# PSA: Reputation has been recalculated for questions

Tags: discussion, reputation, stackexchange

So if you logged in today on any site you might have seen either your Rep go up all of a sudden or this

[image: Notice]

as per the link in the banner, [Stack Overflow is now rewarding Questions more rep](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/)

> We’re recalculating reputation for every Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange individual based on this change. Every question upvote earned in the past will earn a value of ten reputation points retroactively.

this means people will not start seeing some new privileges they didn't have before

[Robotnik on Arqade has summed up the key point in their own Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14712/heads-up-reputation-has-been-recalculated-for-questions) so i'll quote them

> #### Key points:
>
> - The reputation change only applies to questions
> - It has been applied retroactively, so the reputation counts as earned when the vote was cast.
>
>   - This also means that progress towards badges like 'Epic' and "Legendary' will be calculated correctly
> - Downvotes are unaffected, and still give **-2**
> - There is not a clean way to see how much reputation you have gained.
>
>   - The easiest way to get an estimate is probably to use the [Wayback machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXSEb.jpg) on your [user profile page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) and compare your current rep from the most recent snapshot.
>   - A more precise calculation would be: `PreviousRep = CurrentRep - (QuestionUpvotes * 5)`.

Comment: I think such posts are tagged [meta-tag:discussion]

Comment: @NogShine yeh forgot about that

Comment: The meta post from Arqade has since been updated to provide a handy query on [Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/anime/query/1148164/estimated-rep-bump-from-question-upvote-change) to get a rough estimate on how much rep you obtained. I updated the url for the query to use this site instead